# _asm doesnt work in C code, how to enable it

Tags: c++, c, assembly

```
_asm  
{  
//----------------------------------  
    dword_type(DYN_LOADER_START_MAGIC)  
//----------------------------------  
_main_0:  
    pushad  // save the registers context in stack  
    call _main_1  
_main_1:      
    pop ebp  
    sub ebp,offset _main_1 // get base ebp  
...... //many many assembler code line  
}
```

I want to write code injection tool for Windows executables
But this _asm doesn't work gives:
64 C:\Users\ACharyyev\Desktop\test\pemaker5\pemaker\Copy of loader.cpp `_asm' undeclared (first use this function)
There is asm() function seems to be work but I have to convert all vars (e.g. eax to %eax) and put newlines and so on, but _asm {} should work. I couldnt find anything to enable assembler in Project Properties and Compiler properties. Any idea.
Now i use DevCpp on Windows as an IDLE for this project.

Comment: `_asm` and `__asm` are MSVC++ extensions, they don't work in (that extremely old version of) GCC which is what Dev-C++ uses.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: `__asm` works according to the FAQ: http://www.bloodshed.net/faq.html#16.

Comment: @MikeKwan yes, I meant the assembly block thing that he's doing. GCC has that and assembly "templates" or something

Answer (score 3):

`__asm` will work, but you still need to use AT&T since that is what Dev-C++ supports.